# Why is my virtual port linking to the original port in apache?

Tags: windows, php, apache-2.4

I am trying to create two ports 80 and 81 to render different files in my compute. For this I made a virtual host. My httpd-vhost.conf is as following:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\Softwear\Apache\httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14\Apache24\htdocs\2"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\Softwear\Apache\httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14\Apache24\htdocs"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

In my httpd.conf file I have added Listen 81 below Listen 80 line. The problem is both localhost:80 and localhost:81 refer to localhost:80's location.

When I run httpd.exe -S I get no mention of 81 port:

```
D:\Softwear\Apache\httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -S
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "D:/Softwear/Apache/httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14/Apache24"
Main DocumentRoot: "D:/Softwear/Apache/httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14/Apache24/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "D:/Softwear/Apache/httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14/Apache24/logs/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="D:/Softwear/Apache/httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14/Apache24/logs/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "D:/Softwear/Apache/httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14/Apache24/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
```

Answer (score 0):

The file with your virtual hosts is not being included, otherwise there would be extra output from "httpd -S"

Your ServerRoot is "D:/Softwear/Apache/httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14/Apache24" so the default configuration file will be "D:/Softwear/Apache/httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf"

Look at the file, "httpd-vhost.conf" should be included there. Possibly it is still commented out?